# How can I make a Ajax request & response with firefox OS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, firefox-os

I'm having a php function which returns a Json data from db.
I want get all the json from the function and display that into my Firefox App. I tried Jquery Ajax. But its not working.

Any other library or Ajax coding?

```
var a=1;
$.ajax({
     url:"http://localhost/shop/home/home/demo",
     type:"POST",
     data:{b:a},
     success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
     }
});
```

It's not working with firefox app. Help me.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the mozSystem property. Here's an example using native XMLHttpRequest.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({
    mozSystem: true
});
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/shop/home/home/demo");
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};

xhr.send("b=" + a); //serialized data
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks... Short and sweet answer.

Comment: Please help me!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836348/firefox-os-content-security-policy-error-xhr-based-application-in-index-html