# firefox OS Content Security Policy error XHR based application in Index.html?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-os

I got this error in console.

Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src app://fa91d835-176d-4fe7-bd06-fe7f57f11b68").

I tried to create a firefox ajax app to retrieve some data from my codeigniter controller. 
When I check the console it only returns the error. I've only added javascript function outside file. But its saying CSP error.

My Index.Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Privileged app</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A privileged app stub">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xhrapp.js" ></script>
   <link rel="prefetch" type="application/l10n" href="data/locales.ini" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/l10n.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <h1 data-l10n-id="app_title">Privileged empty app</h1>
            <p data-l10n-id="app_description">This app is empty. Fill it with your own stuff!</p>
            <p id="message"></p>
            <input type="text" id="ajax_data" value="">
            <a href="" onclick="xhrapp();"><button>Click</button></a>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Function xhrapp.js

```
function xhrapp(){
    var a=$("#ajax_data").val();
    alert(a);
    console.log("in function");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({
            mozSystem: true
    });
    // xhr.open("POST", "http://blac.byethost7.com/home/index.php/welcome/demo");
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/shop/home/home/demo");
    xhr.send(a);
    xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        // alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
    };


}
```

Please help me!

Comment: That controller having. echo "hi"; only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use attribute `onclick=''` since it violates the CSP

Since you are using jquery, add this instead in your xhrapp.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mybutton").on("click", xhrapp);

});
```

Change your HTML to this:

```
<button id="mybutton">Click</button> <!-- <a> is not needed -->
```

**For more info check:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/CSP

Comment: Its fixed. But I get into another problem :(

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://blac.byethost7.com/home/index.php/welcome/demo. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: If you manage that resource I would recommend to move it to the same domain to avoid headaches!

Comment: How can I move it to the same domain?
I'm running that app in firefox OS emulator on my local system. I also tried in localhost. Same error returns :(

Comment: In the Local folder (app folder)...
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "xhrapplication",
  "description": "A template with the bare minimum structure",
  "launch_path": "/index.html",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/img/icons/icon16x16.png",
    "48": "/img/icons/icon48x48.png",
    "60": "/img/icons/icon60x60.png",
    "128": "/img/icons/icon128x128.png"
  },

Comment: "developer": {
    "name": "Your name",
    "url": "http://example.com"
  },
  "type": "privileged",
  "permissions": {},
  "installs_allowed_from": [
    "*"
  ],
  "locales": {
    "es": {
      "name": "Aplicación vacía privilegiada",
      "description": "Una plantilla con la mínima estructura",
      "permissions": {}
    }
  },
  "default_locale": "en"
}

Comment: Never encountered this problem, but I believe it has something to do with your manifest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest

Comment: You are really awesome :D

The manifest file had the error... 

Thanks @Marcos its worked... I got the "Hi"  from the remote URL...!

Comment: I'm happy to help you, I'm your savior, 2/2 :P!

Comment: Its actually the problem about the template manifest i've chosen. Privleged app to load remote content manifest fixed the problem :D